# Is there a way to create a factor table for spline terms using GAMs in Python's h2o

Tags: python, h2o, gam, bspline, h2o.ai

I have fit a GAM model in h2o with several gam variables (P-splines) using the h2o.estimators.gam package. I'd like to get a table with the factor loading for every level of each gam variable. For example, one of my variables is age, and I need a table of the coefficient for each age.

Answer (score 1):

Right now we do not support categorical columns in generating splines.  It is on our roadmap though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Sorry, my question wasn’t clear. I’m referring to a continuous variable that I’m modeling with splines, but there are 1000 possible values of the continuous variable and I’d like to know the effect of each possible value on the response.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).